# VBA xlwings - variable resolution

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas, xlwings

I am unable to assign a cell value from one spreadsheet to a cell in another spreadsheet. Invalid syntax is thrown at me when I try to. 
Is it not possible to assign them directly? Here's the code..

```
cwb = xlwings.Book(r'%s'%pqcPath+'Metrics Consolidator - Testing.xlsm')
currentWB = xlwings.Book(r'%s'%xPath+f)

for f in files_needed:
    currentWB = xlwings.Book(r'%s'%xPath+f)

    lastRowError = currentWB.sheets('pQC Checklist').range('E' + 
    str(currentWB.sheets('pQC 
    Checklist').cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row

    for i in range(14, lastRowError):

        lastRow = cwb.sheets('Matrix').range('A' + 
        str(cwb.sheets('Matrix').cells.last_cell.row).end('up').row

        **cwb.sheets('Matrix').range('L' + lastRow + 1).Value = 
        currentWB.sheets('pQC Checklist').range('E' + i).Value**

    currentWB.save()
    currentWB.close()
```

Comment: Note that xlwings uses lower case `.value` following Python's standard notation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define your workbook to a variable?

```
dim wb1 as Workbook, wb2 as Workbook, ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
set wb1 = Workbooks("WorkbookName1")
set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

set wb2 = Workbooks("WorkbookName2")
set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

In my experience, excel vba is *extremely* prone to bugs when working with multiple workbooks/worksheets.
I always start by assigning each wb/ws I plan on using to variables.

Comment: Yes, I did.. the following line throws the invalid syntax error. cwb and currentWB have both been recorded                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        cwb.sheets('Matrix').range('L' + lastRow + 1).Value = 
        currentWB.sheets('pQC Checklist').range('E' + i).Value

Comment: Can you create a breakpoint on the "**cwb.sheets" row, then run and see what value is being stored to the variable lastRow.  You can do this but hovering over the variable while the sub is paused at the breakpoint.